# Change date input format PHP/Bootstrap/Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Currently my date input format is mm/dd/yyyy and i want it to be set as dd/mm/yyyy.

How can i change this?

Im using Bootstrap 4

Below my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com /bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-    MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"     crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body style="background-color:white">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-sm col-lg-5 pads rounded border" style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">For</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="date-input" name="order-date" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">CONTINUE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format#answer-30986276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure JS, use: 
`format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

For JQuery, use: 
 `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

If you are using a date picker you can use JQuery/Bootstrap:
 `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});`

Comment: Also it would be helpful to show your bootstrap code next time!  Hope this helps.